# NoClassDefFoundError org/eclipse/swt/SWTError

Tags: java, jar, compilation

I m trying to compile an open source [software](http://code.google.com/p/five/) . The build works fine and results into a jar file "five-server.jar". When I try to run this file from cmd , I get these errors.

```
C:\Users\vickey\code\five-server\dist\main>java -jar five-server.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/SWTError
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: org.devtcg.five.Main. Program will exit.
```

any suggestion what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the classpath so that it includes at least the class org.eclipse.swt.SWTError
or the jar containing it:

```
java -classpath path/to/jar/containing/org.eclipse.swt.SWTError -jar five-server.jar
```

You should also set the Main-class attribute in the manifest file in the `five-server.jar`

Comment: C:\Users\vickey\code\five-server\dist\main>java -classpath c:\Users\vickey\code\five-server\dist\libs\x86\ -j
ar five-server.jar still gives me the same error. c:\Users\vickey\code\five-server\dist\libs\x86\ contains the swt.jar file. After extracting it I see the SWTError class file present. But for some reason it is not getting picked up

Answer (score 5):

The SWT Jar files are platform dependent.
See http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.eclipse.swt.SWTError

e.g. on Windows a suitable jar would be:
org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.1.0.jar

or on Mac OS X:
swt-macosx-3.0m7.jar

and so on. 
You might run into call kinds of followup problems if you add this dependency e.g. whether you are
using 32bit or 64bit libraries.

It is too bad that these kind of dependency problems show up more often than not these days :-(

Answer (score 1):

Following the @Wolfgang Fahl answer, you might download the references here:

**Standard Widget Toolkit » 4.3 x86**

Maven reference:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.swt.org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86.4.3.swt/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86/4.3

Jar file:
http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/swt/org/eclipse/swt/win32/win32/x86_64/4/3/swt/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64/4.3/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64-4.3.jar

**Standard Widget Toolkit » 4.3 x64**

Maven reference: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.swt.org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64.4.3.swt/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64/4.3

Jar file:
http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/swt/org/eclipse/swt/win32/win32/x86_64/4/3/swt/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64/4.3/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64-4.3.jar